# Getting a cannot make a static reference to a non static method when I call AsyncTask<Void.execute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I’m using AsyncTask to load bitmaps in the background.  I created a class Mybackground that inherits from AsyncTask.
If I do the following it works,

```
new MyBackground().execute();
```

But when I call it this way,

```
MyBackground mBackground=new MyBackground();
mBackground.p1=1;
mBackground.p2="tets";
MyBackground.execute();
```

I get the error cannot make a static reference to a non static.
Why am I getting this error.  Is there a way to do this? If not what would be a good way to pass in 2 different arguments, since execute only takes in 1 parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would call `mBackground.execute()` which calls the `execute` method of a particular instance of your `MyBackground` class.

Calling `new MyBackground().execute()` creates a new `MyBackground` instance and then calls execute on that, which is why you don't get the error.

Take a look at [Java: static and instance methods](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html) if you are unsure on what the difference between a static and instance method is.

Static methods do not require an instance of that type to exist, and static properties are shared between all instances of a class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass some data into your `AsyncTask` you can create a new constructor for it:

```
public class MyBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ...
    private int p1;
    private String p2;

    public MyBackground(int p1, String p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    } 
    ...
}
```

You would then use either:

```
MyBackground myBackground = new MyBackground(1,"tets");
myBackground.execute();
// or
MyBackground myBackground = new MyBackground(1,"tets").execute();
```

Joseph Earl has a good explanation of why you are getting the static reference error.

Comment: Hi,Thank you, so simple a solution